# How to check if user is authtificated for first time in Firebase - Android

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentification in an Android application, and I am using Facebook account authentification as an option to sign in the application.

How can i know if the user is sign in the application for the first time or not ?
Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to read the android studio log to see if everything was ok, and to be sure that your code is working, read the [google firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login?hl=es)

There you will see that you need to call the method `registerCallback` to know if you get success on facebook authentication, and use the `handleFacebookAccessToken` method to check if the facebook token obtained before was interchanged by the firebase credential.

If you want to know if this user was registered for the first time, you could [read and write users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) when they are registered on your app.

Hope it helps